I created controller in visual studio and generated views with scaffolding but now it shows error
I am learning dotnet from scratch through docs and chatgpt and creating a project of taskmanager where I created Task model and then used entity framework to create database and all then when I created controller and added Taskdbcontext and Task model in the dialog box it created controller with CRUD operations and View pages for that as well
SO it was all done by not me but it was all generated by scaffolding so how can I face errors As I did what I mentioned above I got 60 errors saying

Error (active)    CS1061  'Task' does not contain a definition for 'Title' and no accessible extension method 'Title' accepting a first argument of type 'Task' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  TaskManager D:\TaskManager\TaskManager\Views\Tasks\Create.cshtml    17

instead of some simple UI and chat GPT told me to look at first line of my cshtml files and add model there
so this was line in my index.cshtml file
@model IEnumerable<Task>


and in rest of files like create details delete and edit the first line was
@model Task

so i updated them to
@model TaskManager.Models.Task

but it still gave error saying the model is not found but I know that the model is there and file is saved as TaskModel.cs and the class name of the model is Task and it shows error when I build the project only
and here is my Task model body saved as Taskmodel.cs
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class Task
{
    [Key] // Ensure this is marking 'Id' as the primary key
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public string Priority { get; set; }
    public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}

so I am confused about what to do now and if someone can suggest me a better way of learning C# and dotnet development it would be great as

while learning c# from scratch and also GPT or copilot are a good idea, doing that completely without non-hallucinating lecture, like a good book, is not.
reason for that is, right now, GPT and copilot are EXTREMELY useful, but you need to know what to ask and what result you want. they are just not good enough to teach you C# yet.
you miss out a lot of knowledge about DI, Servicebuilders, SOLID, etc. if you go that way.   read that instead https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/learn and dont use copilot/gpt to take the work from you, but to explain things,  later on you can use it better
